# Oracle Report returns error on compilation: Identifier 'GET_PRECISION' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, report, oraclereports

I have a standard oracle report, I want to return date parameter from the report. But upon compilation it returns an error that 
Error 201: identifier 'GET_PRECISION' must be declared.

It is related to some missing library.
I need help overcoming this error rest the report yields output fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is called inv.pll . Give me your email in a private message and I send back you this file. Here you are body of this function if it's enough:

```
    GET_PRECISION  ­procedure get_precision (id IN NUMBER) is
begin
srw.attr.mask        :=  SRW.FORMATMASK_ATTR;
--Bug 1403394 Earlier Characters are hard coded now changed.
if id = 0 then srw.attr.formatmask  := '-NNNGNNNGNNNGNN0';
else
if id = 1 then srw.attr.formatmask  := '-NNNGNNNGNNNGNN0D0';
else
if id = 3 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=  '-NNGNNNGNNNGNN0D000';
else
if id = 4 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=   '-NGNNNGNNNGNN0D0000';
else
if id = 5 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=    '-NNNGNNNGNN0D00000';
else
if id = 6 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=    '-NNGNNNGNN0D000000';
else
if id = 7 then srw.attr.formatmask  := '-NNNNNNNNNNN0';
else
if id = 8 then srw.attr.formatmask  := '-NNNNNNNNNNN0D0';
else
if id = 9 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=  '-NNNNNNNNNN0D00';
else
if id = 10 then srw.attr.formatmask  := '-NNNNNNNNNN0D000';
else
if id = 11 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=  '-NNNNNNNNN0D0000';
else
if id = 12 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=   '-NNNNNNNN0D00000';
else
if id = 13 then srw.attr.formatmask  :=    '-NNNNNNN0D000000';
else srw.attr.formatmask  :=  '-NNNGNNNGNNNGNN0D00';
end if; end if; end if; end if; end if; end if;
end if; end if; end if; end if; end if; end if; end if;
srw.set_attr(0,srw.attr);
end;
```